# Magento bundle product price when out of stock

Tags: magento, php

We have a bunch of bundle packages and if one of the items is not available, the bundled product will show "out of stock" which is good. However, the price will show the amount of the available products.

Is there a way to show the full price to include both the available AND unavailable items? Or to just hide the price completely if an item in the bundle is out of stock as this can upset customers when they see a lower price compared to the full price when bundled product is available with all simple items in stock.

Example: http://screencast.com/t/vIKSfcXUQA , that out of stock bundled product is actually over $600 when all items are in stock.

EDIT: Bundle Product price options are set to Dynamic and price view is set to "As low as"

Answer (score 0):

Login in to your Magento Admin go to *System > Configuration*.
On the left column, under *Catalog*, go to *Inventory*.

Under the tab *Stock Options*, you have a ***Display Out of Stock Products*** which you can set to *"No"*.
If that did not work, then Magento is not allowing such a thing, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that temporarily to avoid any confusion for customers.  But ideally, we'd like to be able to still show out of stock items with the full price so customers can still see what products we carry on a regular basis.